# How can i replicate this layout HTML

Tags: html, css

[image: This is what i need mine to look like]

So i am trying to replicate this image above but i am struggling a little bit. Could anyone give me some advice on how to get there. I am struggling with the spacing mainly with the text inputs and the text on the left of the inputs. I am close to replicating the image but need help with the spacing of all the different elements. This is my attempt so far and here is the HTML i used:

```css
li {list-style-type: none;
font-size: 16pt;
}
.mail {
margin: auto;padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 100px;
width: 800px;
background : #ececec;
border: 1px solid silver;
}
.mail h2 {
margin-left: 38px;
}
input {
font-size: 20pt;
}
input:focus, textarea:focus{
background-color: lightyellow;
}
input submit {
font-size: 12pt;
background-color: #aa0000
}
.rq {
color: #FF0000;
font-size: 10pt;
}


p1
{
 float:left;
}

p2
{
 float:left; 
}

p3
{
 float:left;
}

.mail.btn
{
 width: 100%;
    margin-top: 3px;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: #2ec4a5;
    color: white;
}

img{
 display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.b
{
 border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
}

#inputBtn{
 background-color: #b00404;
 color: white;
}

.a{
  margin-top: 50;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-right: 75px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.c{

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>JavaScript form validation - checking non-empty</title>

<link rel='stylesheet' href="css/stylesheet.css" type='text/css' />

<script src="js/javascript.js"></script>

</head><body onload='document.form1.text1.focus()'>



<div class="b">
<h2>Payment Option</h2>
</div>

<p>Debit / Credit Card<img src="image/Mastercard.jpg" alt="Mastercard Logo" width="81" height="56"></p>



<div class="mail">

<form name="form1" action="#">

<ul>

<div class="c">

<p1> Card Number </p1>
</div>


<div class="a">


<li><input type='text' name='CardNumber'/></li><br>

</div>


<p2> Expiration Date </p2>

<select id="Month">
<option  disabled selected>Month</option>
  <option value="January">January</option>
  <option value="February">February</option>
  <option value="March">March</option>
  <option value="April">April</option>
  <option value="May">May</option>
  <option value="June">June</option>
  <option value="July">July</option>
  <option value="August">August</option>
  <option value="September">September</option>
  <option value="October">October</option>
  <option value="November">November</option>
  <option value="December">December</option>
</select>

<select id="Year">
<option  disabled selected>Year</option>
  <option value="2020">2020</option>
  <option value="2021">2021</option>
  <option value="2022">2022</option>
  <option value="2023">2023</option>
  <option value="2024">2024</option>
  <option value="2025">2025</option>
  <option value="2026">2026</option>
  <option value="2027">2027</option>
  <option value="2028">2028</option>
  <option value="2029">2029</option>
  <option value="2030">2030</option>
</select><br><br>

<p3> Security Code </p3>
<li><input type='text' name='text2'/></li>

<p>(3-4 digit code normally found on the back of your card)</p>

<li>&nbsp;</li>


<div class="form-group" id="pay-now">

<li class="continue"><input type="button" id="inputBtn" name="submit" value="Continue"
onclick="cardnumber(document.form1.text1)"/></li>

</div>


<li>&nbsp;</li>

</ul>

</form>

</div>

<script src="js/credit-card-master-validation.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: Here is what mine looks like so far]

Comment: Do you have access to the original web page, or you just have the image?

Comment: Just the image, i would be more than okay if i had access to the webpage

Comment: Can we modify the existing code?

Comment: is there a possibility of using bootstrap will that be acceptable ? or everything should be pure html single page ? if you want pure HTML, then simply use `<table>` tag

Comment: yes the existing code can be modified, honestly i have no idea what bootstrap is

Comment: You should use [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

Comment: @Manjuboyz yes you modify existing code

Comment: By the way, you have invalid HTML in your code (`<p2>` is not an HTML element, `<div>`s cannot be inside lists, etc...) and you really shouldn't be using lists (`<ul>`) for that. You should use [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label), too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this bootstrap grid

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-2">Card Number</div>
   <div class="col-sm-3"><input type='text' name='CardNumber' /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-2">Expiration Date</div>
   <div class="col-sm-1">
   <select id="Month">
    <option disabled selected>Month</option>
    <option value="January">January</option>
    <option value="February">February</option>
    <option value="March">March</option>
    <option value="April">April</option>
    <option value="May">May</option>
    <option value="June">June</option>
    <option value="July">July</option>
    <option value="August">August</option>
    <option value="September">September</option>
    <option value="October">October</option>
    <option value="November">November</option>
    <option value="December">December</option>
   </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
    <select id="Year" style="margin-left:10px">
    <option disabled selected>Year</option> 
     <option value="2020">2020</option>
     <option value="2021">2021</option>
     <option value="2022">2022</option>
     <option value="2023">2023</option>
     <option value="2024">2024</option>
     <option value="2025">2025</option>
     <option value="2026">2026</option>
     <option value="2027">2027</option>
     <option value="2028">2028</option>
     <option value="2029">2029</option>
     <option value="2030">2030</option>
    </select>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">Security Code</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2"><input type='text' name='text2' /></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

which is ready start your design